# why $(\theta _{1}\circ \theta _{2})^{\vee }\subset(\theta _{2}\circ \theta _{1})^{\vee } $

Tags: universal-algebra

[image]

my questiones at this theorem:
i coud not undrestand $a\Rightarrow b$
and why $(\theta _{1}\circ \theta _{2})^{\vee }\subset(\theta _{2}\circ \theta _{1})^{\vee } $
please guide me?

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the definition of the relational inverse operation?  Assuming you do, then for binary relations $R$ and $S$, verify the following: if $R \subseteq S$, then $R^{\vee} \subseteq S^{\vee}$.  Then check that $(\theta_1\circ \theta_2)^{\vee} = \theta_2^{\vee}\circ \theta_1^{\vee}$.